# compiling android source Code

Tags: android, android-studio, compilation

What is the easiest way for someone to re-compile an android source code?

I am leaving a project to the hands of a colleague who is non techie. The project is created using android studio.Periodically, the colleague will make minimal adjustments to the csv file in the source code, re-compile it, and distribute the new apk file.

Does the colleague need to install Android Studio  just to recompile the code? What are other options?

Comment: I understand your issue, but would it be better to externalize this csv data with a API call for instance ?

Comment: how would that work for this scenario? I haven't gotten around to learning much on APIs yet. My users are mostly only offline, and they only get to update the app by downloading the apk to their phones.

Comment: Well, it may be overkill in your case, but what I was thinking is updating the csv through a website - the non tech way - then the app will fetch the csv if it does not have it already in cache. You can add the "update" feature that will fetch a newer version of the csv within the app. If the user are online to update the app by downloading the apk, there also are to update the csv through the app. It seems better to me because it's separate the code from to data (SoC). Anyway, a choice is often a matter of  compromise.

Answer (score 0):

With the Gradle Wrapper you can run the following command from terminal:

./gradlew assembleRelease

This will compile the code and output the Release APK to your apps build/outputs/apk directory.